# Global variable set from file read doesn't update with app restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I made changes to a YML file locally that is read in from an initializer and restarted the Rails environment, but the old version of the data from that file persisted in application state. The file was saved and checked into version control (just in case that was the issue for whatever reason).

The code itself was simple:

```
# config/initializers/tagging.rb
require 'yaml'

$tag_refs = YAML.load_file("static/tagging_lookup.yml")
```

The original data looked like this:

```
{
    "tag_types" => {
        "users" => [
            [0] "skill",
            [1] "availability"
        ],
         "jobs" => [
            [0] "skill"
        ]
    },
        "users" => {
               "skill" => [
            [0] "skilled",
            [1] "expert",
            [2] "experienced",
            [3] "flexible",
            [4] "communicative"
        ],
        "availability" => [
            [0] "part-time",
            [1] "full-time",
            [2] "gig",
            [3] "contract"
        ]
    }
}
```

This was fixed by 'unsetting' and 'resetting' the variable:

```
# config/initializers/tagging.rb
require 'yaml'

$tag_refs = nil
$tag_refs = YAML.load_file("static/tagging_lookup.yml")
```

The updated (and correct) data looked like this:

```
{
    "tag_types" => {
        "users" => [
            [0] "skill",
            [1] "availability"
        ],
         "jobs" => [
            [0] "benefit",
            [1] "experience",
            [2] "availability"
        ]
    },
        "users" => {
               "skill" => [
            [0] "skilled",
            [1] "expert",
            [2] "experienced",
            [3] "flexible",
            [4] "communicative"
        ],
        "availability" => [
            [0] "part-time",
            [1] "full-time",
            [2] "gig",
            [3] "contract"
        ]
    },
         "jobs" => {
             "benefit" => [
            [0] "PTO",
            [1] "remote",
            [2] "flexible",
            [3] "supplied equipment"
        ],
        "availability" => [
            [0] "part-time",
            [1] "full-time",
            [2] "gig",
            [3] "contract"
        ],
          "experience" => [
            [0] "skilled",
            [1] "expert"
        ]
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here? Does Rails persist global variable states if the same code is run against it? Does this have something to do with the default file caching functionality in Rails?

**EDIT:**
Upon further investigation, it appears that it doesn't work without `$tag_refs = nil` when I add a new key to the YML file under nested context. For example:

```
tag_types:
  jobs: ["benefit", "industry"]
jobs:
  benefit: ["PTO", "remote", "flexible", "supplied equipment"]
  industry: ["food"]
```

When changed to:

```
tag_types:
  jobs: ["benefit", "industry", "lodging"]
jobs:
  benefit: ["PTO", "remote", "flexible", "supplied equipment"]
  industry: ["food"]
  lodging: ["on-site"]
```

Will NOT include the 'lodging' key in the read `jobs` values.

Comment: Where in the code are you reading `$tag_refs`?

Comment: Is there any chance you're setting `$tag_refs` more than once?

Comment: It's being used in a module/concern for the tagging system. The reference is called in an `included` block on initialization.

Comment: @JakeWorth No, it's the only reference that is setting the state of the variable in the app through all of the functionality. The only other invocations are through reads like: `tagging_types = $tag_refs["tag_types"][klass.name.downcase.pluralize]` or `@valid_class_names = $tag_refs["tag_types"].map{|k,v| k}`. I have tests that would have caught it being set in any other code outside of the few places where I read it directly.

Comment: I can only think of one explanation from the above information; some process is running that's keeping `$tag_refs` in memory between Rails server restarts. Not sure what that could be; maybe Spring?

Comment: That might actually be what's doing it. That's about the only thing that made sense to me when I looked into it more, too. Thanks for the input!